# Get name of an XElement (Visual Basic)

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an xml document that contains the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
  <shop>
    <Item>content1</Item>
    <Item>content2</Item>
    <Item>content3</Item>
  </shop>
  <todo>
    <Item>content1</Item>
    <Item>content2</Item>
    <Item>content3</Item>
  </todo>
</root>
```

I wanted to read the xml file and get the names of the child elements from root ("shop" and "todo" in this example) so that I can only create another group with a different name than the ones that already exist.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XElement

```
    'test data
    Dim xe As XElement = <root>
                             <shop>
                                 <Item>content1</Item>
                                 <Item>content2</Item>
                                 <Item>content3</Item>
                             </shop>
                             <todo>
                                 <Item>content1</Item>
                                 <Item>content2</Item>
                                 <Item>content3</Item>
                             </todo>
                         </root>

    For Each el As XElement In xe.Elements
        Dim s As String = el.Name.LocalName
        Debug.WriteLine(s)
    Next
```